# JsonHttpRequestInitializer() method is not resolved in android

Tags: android, json, google-drive-api

i am working on Google drive. After long long time i am able to upload file at Google drive in my account. But When I am trying to access the Google drive account from my android app , I am not able download file and problem is that following methods is not resolved.

```
Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);

b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(JSonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                        DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                        driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
                        driveRequest.setKey("186535896147");
                        driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android, use a `GoogleAccountCredential` object to authorize the requests instead of interception requests in a way you're doing above.

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
b = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

The full flow is already implemented on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android, please use it as a reference.

Comment: i not able to get right way .my app is crashing.please please if don't mind can u share ur code with me.